# How do I convert these coordinates to google map readable coordinates?

Tags: php, google-maps, coordinate-systems

I need to convert coordinates in the following form:

```
N42-53.9° 
W072-16.2°
```

Into something that is like the following:

```
-90.7311
0.346944
```

A php function would be greatly appreciated - or just a formula would also be nice enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an [online JS calculator](http://www.fcc.gov/mb/audio/bickel/DDDMMSS-decimal.html) and a [PHP solution](http://www.web-max.ca/PHP/misc_6.php):

```
<?php
function DMStoDEC($deg,$min,$sec)
{
// Converts DMS ( Degrees / minutes / seconds ) 
// to decimal format longitude / latitude

    return $deg+((($min*60)+($sec))/3600);
}    

function DECtoDMS($dec)
{
// Converts decimal longitude / latitude to DMS
// ( Degrees / minutes / seconds ) 

// This is the piece of code which may appear to 
// be inefficient, but to avoid issues with floating
// point math we extract the integer part and the float
// part by using a string function.

    $vars = explode(".",$dec);
    $deg = $vars[0];
    $tempma = "0.".$vars[1];

    $tempma = $tempma * 3600;
    $min = floor($tempma / 60);
    $sec = $tempma - ($min*60);

    return array("deg"=>$deg,"min"=>$min,"sec"=>$sec);
}    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with simple mathematics:

```
arcsecond is 1⁄3,600 of a degree
arcminute is 1/60 of a degree

S,E negative, N,W positive

example: S 23° 25' 33.8: -1 * 23+25/60+33.8/3600 = -23,426055555555555555555555555556°
```